# Node counter in Binary Search Tree

Tags: python

basically... i'm trying to get my "count" method to count how many nodes there are in the tree... but the recursion isnt working.. how do i do it?

```
'''
Created on Jul 11, 2013
To practice building native recursion things
@author: bailey
'''
class AllWords :
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_tree = Tree()
  def add(self, fresh_word):
    self.my_tree.insert(fresh_word)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.my_tree)

class Tree :
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = Blob()
    self.size = 0 # initialising size to be zero
    self.tutti = "" # to hold all content data
    self.left_edges = 0
    self.right_edges = 0
    self.x = 0
    self.b = 0

  def __str__(self):
    if self.is_empty() :
        return "This tree is empty"
    else :  # so the tree at least has something in the root
        self.tutti += "This tree has depth = " + str(self.get_depth())
        self.tutti +=  ", and contains the " + str(self.size) + " objects:\n"
        self.tutti += ", and has " + str(self.x) + " nodes \n"
        self.tutti += "This tree has " + str(self.left_edges) + " edges on left.\n"
        self.tutti += "This tree has " + str(self.right_edges) + " edges on right.\n"
        self.tutti += "This tree has " + str(self.edge_stats()) + " edges in total.\n"
        self.grab_everything(self.root) # start at the root
        return self.tutti

  def grab_everything(self, my_blob):
    if not my_blob.left_is_empty() : # if there's something on the left
        self.grab_everything(my_blob.left)
    self.tutti = self.tutti + str(my_blob.data) + ", " # update tutti
    if not my_blob.right_is_empty() : # if there's something on the right
        self.grab_everything(my_blob.right)

  def is_empty(self):
    return self.size == 0


  def insert(self, something):
    if self.is_empty() : # put the something at the root
        self.root = Blob(something)
        self.size = 1
    else : # find where to put it by starting search at the root
        self.insert_at_blob(something, self.root)
        self.size += 1

  def insert_at_blob(self, something, blob):
    if something < blob.data : # look left
        if blob.left_is_empty() :
            blob.set_left( Blob(something) )
        else : # keep looking to the left
            self.insert_at_blob(something, blob.left) 
    else : # look right
        if blob.right_is_empty() :
            blob.set_right( Blob(something) )
        else : # keep looking to the right
            self.insert_at_blob(something, blob.right)         

  def get_depth(self): # depth is max number of edges from root outwards
    if self.is_empty() : 
        return -1 # my choice of answer if there's nothing there
    else : # note: will define a root-only tree to have depth 0
        return self.get_subdepth(self.root)

  def get_subdepth(self, blob):
    if not blob.left_is_empty() :
        left_depth = self.get_subdepth(blob.left)
    else : 
        left_depth = -1 # since that node is empty
    if not blob.right_is_empty() : 
        right_depth = self.get_subdepth(blob.right)
    else : 
        right_depth = -1 # since that node is empty
    return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1

  def count_left_only(self):
    if not self.root.left_is_empty():
        self._count_left_only(self.root.left)
    else :
        print("There are no left edges.")

  def _count_left_only(self, blob):
    if not blob.left_is_empty():
        self._count_left_only(blob.left)
    self.left_edges += 1

  def count_right_only(self):
    if not self.root.right_is_empty():
        self._count_right_only(self.root.right)
    else :
        print("There are no right edges.")

  def _count_right_only(self, blob):
    if not blob.right_is_empty():
        self._count_right_only(blob.right)
    self.right_edges += 1

  def edge_stats(self):
    return self.left_edges + self.right_edges

  def count(self, blob):
    if blob == None:
        return(0)
    if not blob.left_is_empty()and not blob.right_is_empty():
        self.x = self.x + 1
    else:
            return (1 + self.count(blob.left) + self.count(blob.right))

class Blob : # a node class to hold data in a binary tree
  def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

  def set_data(self, thing):
    self.data = thing
  def set_left(self, blob):
    self.left = blob
  def set_right(self, blob):
    self.right = blob

  def left_is_empty(self): 
    return self.left is None
  def right_is_empty(self): 
    return self.right is None

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)


import Searching



tout = Searching.AllWords()
tout.add(20)
tout.add(15)
tout.add(35)
tout.add(17)
tout.add(33)
tout.add(12)
tout.add(43)
tout.my_tree.count(tout)
tout.my_tree.count_right_only()
tout.my_tree.count_left_only()
print( str(tout) )
```

i get 0 but i should be getting 7

Comment: `Tree` has that method, but `AllWords` doesn't. You are passing in an `AllWords` object as `blob` in `Tree.count()`.

Comment: Also don't compare to singleton `None` via `==` but using `is` in your `count` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tree` has that method, but `AllWords` doesn't. You are passing in an `AllWords` object as `blob` in `Tree.count()` on the line that says `tout.my_tree.count(tout)`, because you have declared `tout = Searching.AllWords()`. You probably meant to make it a `Tree`.

Comment: it worked now but my method isnt doing what it was supposed to... :<

Comment: @Panthy Well, now's a good time for you to edit your post with the expected output so we can figure out what's going on!

Comment: @Panthy What you've written has the same problem as before. I think now that you meant to write `tout.my_tree.count(tout.root)`.

Comment: @Panthy *How* does it not work? What output are you getting? You have to tell us that.

Comment: if i did tout.my-tree.root im getting 1 as the output of the count fuction

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33729/discussion-between-2rs2ts-and-panthy)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> tout.my_tree.count(tout.my_tree.root)

because `tout` is not an instance of `Blob`

Answer (score 0):

```
tout.my_tree.count(tout)
```

You're passing in 'tout', an instance of AllWords, but count calls the righty_isempty and left_is_empty methods, which are not present on AllWords, hence the error.